# Why are the lengths of fpr['micro'] and tpr['micro] differing over multiple runs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I have applied the following code from the [scikit-learn website roc documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html)  for creating a ROC curve for my own data problem.

But now I have a problem with the following part:

```
# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
```

I wanted to take the average of the false positive rate values and of the true positive rate values. But each run fpr["micro"] seems to be of a different length. How is this possible?

My code:

```
# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(2):
   fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_valid, y_score)
   roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
print(fpr)

# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area

fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_valid.ravel(), 
y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
```

Both y_valid and y_score are arrays with length 100.
fpr and tpr are changing in length everytime.

Comment: Okay I now came to the conclusion that the false positive rates and true positive rates are differing in length each run as well, so now I am curious why that is the case?

Comment: What does each run mean? Does your own data changes with each run? You should post the whole code and shape of your data and the tpr, fpr for each run.

Comment: Each run means everytime I press 'run my code'. My data is always the same, so also the same each run. But I understand now that the thresholds are changing the fpr and tpr everytime. Is there a possibility to get fixed thresholds?

Comment: All I want is to create an average ROC and therefore I need the average fpr and tpr of each run. But if they are differing in length due to the computed thresholds then that is not possible. So can I get fixed thresholds in a certain way?

Comment: Are you following the linked code exactly. Can you show your code? Have you set the random number seed as in that link?

Comment: Yes I am following the linked code exactly. Do you mean the random state variable? I do not use that because I do not want to add noise.

Comment: There's your problem

Comment: Again. Please add the full code if you want any help. Also from where do you you get the idea that random_state only adds noise?

Comment: I do not see the point of adding those lines to add the noise? Code is added in main post.